# MVC download file from API and retun as result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, model-view-controller, download

I have a requirement to pass a file through an MVC action method. 
To download it from a Web API method and return it as a result.

The code I have is assembled from a few answers here on SO and some other references.

The problem is that the file seems to be locked by the download process when I try to return it as a result. I thought that the tsk.Wait() wold solve the problem.

Perhaps someone knows of a better solution?

```cs
using (var client = HttpClientProvider.GetHttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    await client.GetAsync("api/Documents/" + fileName).ContinueWith(
    (requestTask) =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

        if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
        }
        if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        }

        path = Path.Combine(GetDocsMapPath(), fileName);

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task  tsk = response.Content.ReadAsFileAsync(path, true).ContinueWith(
        (readTask) =>
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            process.Start();
        });
        tsk.Wait();

        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        resp.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        return resp;
    });
}


        public static Task ReadAsFileAsync(this HttpContent content, string filename, bool overwrite)
        {
            string pathname = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
            if (!overwrite && File.Exists(filename))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("File {0} already exists.", pathname));
            }

            FileStream fileStream = null;
            try
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(pathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                return content.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith(
                     (copyTask) =>
                     {
                         fileStream.Close();
                         fileStream.Dispose();
                     });
            }
            catch
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                {
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, I don't see any useful function achieved by the process you launch, apart from locking your file, which you don't want.

try removing these lines and retrying.

```
.ContinueWith(
(readTask) =>
{
   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
   process.Start();
});
```

**Edit:** Using `FilePathResult`

I don't know about your exact requirements, but if your goal is to return a file that you have the path for; then the easiest is to return a FilePathResult which will take care of reading and returning the contents of the file to the requester.

```
public FilePathResult GetFile()
{
    //put your logic to determine the file path here
    string name = ComputeFilePath();
    //verify that the file actually exists and retur dummy content otherwise
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("File Not Found");
        }
    }
    return File(name, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

if you are sure of what type your content is , change the mime type accordingly, otherwise it's better to leave it as a binary data.